# How can I run the Delphi XML schema binding generator from the command line?

Tags: xml, delphi, command-line, binding, xsd

For build automation, I would like to invoke the XML Data Binding Wizard in Delphi from a build script. I have found the WSDLImp.exe, but this tool seems to generate WSDL based Delphi code only.

Is the XML schema binding wizard (which generates Delphi code for XSD files) available as a command line tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is a Wizard, it is by definition a UI kinda thing, not a command line one.
Maybe you mean as a separate exe that you can launch without Delphi?
AFAIK, it is not possible.
FYI, it is part of the dclnet design time package. The class of the wizard-dialog is TXMLNewBindingDlg.

Comment: Yes, I mean a separate exe. The WSDL Importer thingy is available in two flavours too - as a wizard and as an exe. So maybe I could write an application which feeds all input to the TXMLNewBindingDlg?

Comment: @mjn - have you gone any further with this? I have the same question/problem.

Comment: Here is my recent question on this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775102/data-binding-wizard-in-delphi-xe-can-it-be-configured-to-map-to-msxml-interface]